# Get server time without server

Tags: http, time

Is there any service that I can use to get server time with HTTP, I don't want to be depended on user local time, and I don't have server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use public time servers to set your system time over http. The usual method involves `ntp` services which has added additional security over the past four or five years. See this article [**Set time using reputable public time servers**](https://superuser.com/questions/350391/public-reputable-sources-of-time-sync-via-http-to-use-where-ntp-is-blocked).

Answer (score 1):

Make a request to http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now to get the utc time. The problem with this is that there is a timespan between sending the request and getting the response. Let's suppose you have sent the request in `t1` and you have received the response in `t2`. `t2 - t1` might be tens of seconds, which affects the preciseness of the time. An acceptable approach is to calculate `t2 - t1` and add that value to the date you have received as a response to your request.

This answer assumes that you have to do this with HTTP and cannot use it with NTP.

Answer (score 0):

If NTP is blocked on your network, you can get the time via http using one of the following

- [HTTP Time Protocol / HTPdate](http://www.vervest.org/fiki/bin/view/HTP/WebHome)
- [TimeAPI](http://www.timeapi.org/)